# How to test if a number is prime and 9 digits long in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code to detect a password with an algorithm that checks if the number is prime and 9 digits long

```js
function passwordIsGiven() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var passwordLength = password.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < password; i++) {
    if (password % i == 0) {
      isPrime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isPrime && passwordLength == 9) {
    window.alert("Correct");
    window.location.replace("/html/index.html");
  } else {
    window.alert("Wrong code. Try again.");
  }
}
```

```html
<p>ENTER PASSCODE TO CONTINUE</p>
<input type="password" id="password">
<br><br>
<button type="submit" id="passwordButton" onClick="passwordIsGiven()">Submit</button>
```

Even with a correct 9 digit prime number it always says that its wrong.

Comment: for prime checking, only loop until numbers square root. that's enough. Also you need to set isPrime=true; somewhere.

Comment: Anything % 1 == 0. Also you don't define `isPrime` inside the function, so it is effectively global. You could improve the UX by adding `maxlength="9"` pattern="^\d{9}$"` to the `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:
And you must convert the value to a number using:

`var password = Number(document.getElementById("password").value);`

```
function passwordIsGiven() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var passwordLength = password.toString().length;
  let isPrime = true;
  for (let i = 2; i < password; i++) {
    if (password % i == 0) {
      isPrime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isPrime && passwordLength === 9) {
    window.alert("Correct");
    window.location.replace("/html/index.html");
  } else {
    window.alert("Wrong code. Try again.");
  }
}
```

And also add a check for num ===1...as it is is neither a prime nor a composite number.

Answer (score 0):

I would go on a modular approce and split the test to two function. one which test the isPrime case and the other one which test the length.

```js
const isPrime = num => {
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++){
    if(num % i === 0){
           return false;
     }
   }
  return num > 1;
}

const is9digit = number => {
   return number.toString().length;
}

const isPasswordValid = number => is9digit(number) && isPrime(number);

const testNumber = isPasswordValid(333);

if (testNumber) {
   window.alert("Correct");
   window.location.replace("/html/index.html");
}
else {
   window.alert("Wrong code. Try again.");
}
```